# How can I search exactly the same phrase or sentence on Google, Yahoo, or the like?

Tags: microsoft-word

Example) cell, cells, or composition;

--> If I try with "cell, cells, or composition;" on google, I get the list containing ANY ONE of the words, not containing exactly the same phrase.

Answer (score 0):

In Google, you need to type `"cell, cells, or composition;"`,
***including the quotes***. 
You will get [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cell,+cells,+or+composition%3B%22&filter=0).

Comment: This is just one simple example.

Comment: What  do you mean?